# How to optimize Sphinx search for fuzzy text matching?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, sphinx

Situation: I have a MySQL DB with 2mil records in total containing English and Chinese text words and corpus along with their relationships. It is on a dedicated server with 1.5G of RAM with 2.26Ghz dual core CPU. When searching with a string containing more than 30 Chinese characters, it takes around 4 seconds to get a result. This is too slow.

Search method: When running a query, once there are 4 or more words that match, consider the query a success and then sort the results by relevance and pick the one that's the highest match.

Here is a snippet of how it is done right now:

```
$this->sphinx->ResetFilters();
$this->sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
//Sort by relevance
$this->sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
$this->sphinx->SetArrayResult(true);
//Get 10 results
$this->sphinx->SetLimits(0,10);
//Filter the length
$this->sphinx->SetFilterRange('en_length', 10,50);
```

How can I improve the performance of the search? I want this under 1 second if possible. I've tried using SPH_MATCH_ALL and that works really fast. I believe the problem may be the matching mode that is being used for fuzzy match?

**UPDATE:**
Using the quorum operator should be faster but using it returns unexpected values:

This is the result when using the OR operator (normal):
[image]
And this is how it looks with the Quorum operator (corrupted):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Filtering by non-FT attribute might be slow. If you are looking to get document with 4 or more matches you may want to use quorum operator:

```
"get me any document with more than four matches"/4
```

this requires SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED mode to be enabled

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi.I tried this and the returned values are corrupted. The search returns an assoc array and the values are not correct. But when I switch to using the OR operator, it is fine. By using the OR operator, the performance is still just as bad as using SPH_MATCH_ANY.

Comment: Are you running 2.0.x? I see fixes related to quorum since 1.x

Comment: Yes. 2.0.1. Which fixes are you referring to? Is this related? For example. The values that I expect is a integer that is 2 digits. But the quorum operator returns the values and some are changed into a very big value with many digits, which seems almost arbitrary.

Comment: Quorum doesn't return anything - it's just filter documents. Values returned based only on ranker settings and are the same as for any other operators - basically set of ids and some meta information.

Comment: result sample would be useful to have - it may be a bug indeed.